# How to unmount all root level components in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is there a way to get all root elements in React?

I have a situation where elements are being created at the root via ReactDOM.render, however they are not being unmounted when my component unmounts.

I would like to get all elements, other than AppContainer and then unmount them when my component upmounts, is this possible?

[image]

Comment: What's the relationship between AppContainer  and other components? The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that could explain what's going on.

Comment: I am adding custom react components to a datatable, I am confused at why they are going in at the root, as they should be going in under the td.

Comment: as per this example ... https://stackoverflow.com/a/44204235/3284707

Comment: You need to keep track of them and unmount manually with unmountComponentAtNode when they should be unmounted. I cannot say how this should be done in your case because you didn't show your own code. The question you've linked uses jQuery, while you likely not. MCVE is a requirement for SO questions because even if you think your case is the same as in another question, it may differ.

Answer (score 4):

root components rendered with ReactDOM aren't aware of each other.

to unmount a component not in the tree of an unmounting component, you could do something along these lines:

```
const App1Component = <div>app1</div>;
const app1 = document.getElementById("app1")
ReactDOM.render(<App1Component/>, app1);

export class AppContainer extends React.Component {
  componentWillUnmount() {
    // ummount other components not in this tree
    if (app1) 
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(app1);
  }
}
```

basically, whenever your 'main' component is unmounting, call `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode` with your other root elements DOM nodes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am not sure how I can accomplish this, as the elements are created dynamically when the datatable is created, as per the link stackoverflow.com/a/44204235/3284707 therefore I do not have a refernece to the td values when the component unmounts?

Comment: well, technically, you could try obtain their ref using `getElementById`.
a better way would be to assign a react ref to each root element's DOM node.